# Bootstrap span badge pull/float right not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have the following code section and I'm trying to put the badge on the rightmost part of the `list-item`, but somehow it keeps staying next to the text whatever I use ( style="float: right;" / class="pull-righ" / class="float-righ")

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">

            <div class="col-2">

                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item active"><h4>Groups</h4></li>
                    @foreach($project->groups()->get() as $key=>$group)
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="{{$group->name}}">{{$group->name}}<span class="badge badge-default pull-right"> {{$group->jobs()->count()}}</span></li>


                    @endforeach

                </ul>

            </div>


        </div>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/v4udh4Lc/7/

Comment: can you share the link of sample in jsfiddle or github

Comment: share a demo link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v4udh4Lc/7/